# JS: wrong UTC time

Tags: javascript, utc

I have a unix timestamp. I want to render it as UTC time

In JS console:

```
var a = new Date(); 
var res = a.getUTCDay()+ '-' + a.getUTCMonth() + '-' + a.getUTCFullYear(); 
res;
```

The result is "3-11-2013", but the value of 'a' variable is "Wed, 04 Dec 2013 16:28:03 GMT"

What is wrong?

Comment: Months are zero based, and it seems you're missing a month and a day

Comment: You are getting confused. `a.getUTCDay()` is day of the week. Not the date.

Comment: Always read the documentation before you are using a method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. It explains what `getUTCDay` and `getUTCMonth` return.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is wrong?

[`getUTCDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay) returns the day of the week, not the day of the month:

> The `getUTCDay()` method returns the day of the week in the specified date according to universal time, where 0 represents Sunday.

[`getUTCMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth) returns the month, 0 based:

> The value returned by `getUTCMonth` is an integer between 0 and 11 corresponding to the month. 0 for January, 1 for February, 2 for March, and so on.

You want to use [`.getUTCDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate) instead and add `+1` to the return value of `.getUTCMonth`:

```
var res = [a.getUTCDate(), a.getUTCMonth() + 1, a.getUTCFullYear()].join('-');
```

Answer (score 5):

The `getUTCDay()` and `getUTCMonth()` are both index based (starts with 0), you need to +1 theme to get the "real" value

Comment: Correct, but `getUTCDay()` is actually the wrong method to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your codebase is very small, I would refrain from using these poor native JS date formatting functions and just import [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com).